# Include php code into php file

Tags: php

I'm not a programmer so I need help with something I guess could be easy to any php programmer. I would like to include a php code that I have, into a PHP file. 
Code is in a div:

```
<div style="position: fixed;
 background: rgb(226, 30, 30);bottom:0;"><?php
 $min=819;
 $max=852;
 echo rand($min,$max);
?></div>
```

and the file that I'm trying to insert this starts obviously with

```
<?php ....
```

How can I insert that div with the php code correctly without getting any errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wherever you want the other PHP file included, you use `include('the_name_of_the_other_php_file.php');`

Comment: where you want to include ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i assume you want to do:
1. You want a .php file.
2. the php. file must display(echo) the div aswell as the php code.

Here is how i would do it:

```
<?php
$min=819;
$max=852;
$random = rand($min,$max);

echo ('<div style="position: fixed;
background: rgb(226, 30, 30);bottom:0;">');
echo ($random);
echo ('</div>');
```

To make the code easier to read i start off with declaring variables as well as the rand. This way i can just call the variable in the echo. i use the ' mark up since you use " in your html code. this way it will ignore the " and echo it as html.

Hope this helps

Comment: Of all answers this is the one that is closer to what I was looking for, however I'm getting an error in last line..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the following statement:

```
<?php include "filename.php" ?>
```

put this line where you want to put your php file with correct filename(if they are not in same path then you have to define the path also.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I insert it directly into the php file? I mean being part of the file and without including an external php file? –  Robertoss

If you are trying to include the code directly into lets say **file.php**, without requiring another **tobeincluded.php** file, then simply copy and paste the code into **file.php**.

Since you mentioned that **file.php** starts with `<?php`, make sure you close it off with `?>` before you insert the code. Then, open `<?php` again after the code you inserted.

For example:

```
<?php
// Original code here...

// Insert this:
?>

<!-- insert your code here -->
<div style="position: fixed;
background: rgb(226, 30, 30);bottom:0;">
<?php
$min=819;
$max=852;
echo rand($min,$max);
?>
</div>
<?php
// ^ Add this back in
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include de .php file:

```
vars.php
<?php

$color = 'verde';
$fruta = 'manzana';

?>

test.php
<?php

echo "Una $fruta $color"; // Una

include 'vars.php';

echo "Una $fruta $color"; // Una manzana verde

?>
```

HTH